# File handling to delete the contents of the file / Delete the file itelf

Tags: perl, file-io, mod-perl

I have written a perl script which opens a file, writes content to the file and closes it.

```
open FILE, ">file.txt" or die $!;
print FILE $str;
close FILE;
```

once the contents are written to the file  i need the contents of the file to be deleted or the file itself should be deleted.Is there a way to do it.?

I searched online and found out that the following operations can be performed.

```
mode    operand create  truncate
read/write  +<      
read/write  +>  ✓   ✓
read/append +>> ✓
```

But i couldn't find any information related to deleting the contents of the file or deleting the file itself. ( Note : I need the file to be deleted after the contents are written to it).

Comment: Erm... why write to a file if you're going to delete it right after?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html

Comment: @raina77ow That's part of my school assignment.I need to open a file ,write to it and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use lexical file handles and the 3 argument form of open.

Instead of

```
open FILE, ">file.txt" or die $!;
print FILE $str;
close FILE;
```

use

```
open my $fh, ">", "file.txt" or die $!;
print $fh $str;
close $fh;
```

To delete a file, you can do

```
unlink "file.txt" or warn "Could not delete: $!";
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html

Answer (score 0):

A couple of people have given you the answer. But here's how you could probably have worked it out for yourself.

- The official Perl documentation is at http://perldoc.perl.org/.
- The documentation for all of Perl's built-in functions is at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html.
- In that document, is a section entitled [Perl Functions by Category](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#Perl-Functions-by-Category).
- That section contains a list of "Functions for filehandles, files, or directories". That contains links to about twenty functions. Even if you don't recognise one that obviously deletes files (I admit that "unlink" is a slightly obscure name) you can easily clink each of those links to read more detail about each function.
- And when you get to [unlink](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) you'll see the description starts "Deletes a list of files". And one files is a (very short!) list of files.